# Is it possible to put multiple versions of Oracle.DataAccess.dll on the same machine?

Tags: oracle11g

My group has developed several apps that were optimized for the Oracle 11.2.0.1 client and older versions.  I recently installed the latest Oracle 11.2.0.3 client to take advantage of the Entity Framework support.  Some of the older apps don't work with the new client.  I am hoping to allow apps that require both the latest 11.2.0.3 client and older versions to survive in harmony on our client's machines.  Is there a way to do this?

I have one machine with Oracle 11.2.0.1.  I tried to manually load Oracle.DataAccess.dll 11.2.0.3 into the GAC, but the app that depends on it still doesn't work.  Is there something else that I need to do?

This is what my GAC looks like:

[image]

And here are the policy files:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so my colleagues helped me find a solution to this.  For some reason, the OraOLEDB11.dll wasn't registered, and so when we registered it with the following command,

> Regsvr32 C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\OraOLEDB11.dll

(the path to the client home may be different for you), it worked.

With the 11.2.0.3 client installed, and by registering this .dll, the software that was developed on the 11.2.0.1 platform worked correctly with the new 11.2.0.3 client.